# Java - Use of DB instance with SQL Server for XLS Export

Tags: java, sql-server

I'm using an instance of a DB class to get data and fill a excel file, during the process, I change a Date field in order to display a specific date, and as it is a DB instance, when i do that, it changes the data in the DB.

```
List<UserInstance> instances = em.createQuery("...query...")
                                 .setParameter("accountNumber", accountNumber)
                                 .getResultList();        

List<Object[]> instancesUsed = em.createNativeQuery("...query...")
                                 .setParameter(1, accountNumber)
                                 .getResultList();

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

for (UserInstance p: instances) {
    for(Object[] o: instancesUsed) {
        if (o[0].toString().equals(p.getNumber())) {
                try {
                    p.setLastUsedDate(df.parse(o[4].toString()));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to change the data(setLastUsedDate) in the instance without changing the database, how can i handle that? Can i copy the instance in some kind of temporary instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your object is currently managed (attached to a session), so anything you do to it will reflect on the DB without calling persist/update.

You can detach an object from the session using  `Session.evict()` or `EntityManager.detach(object)` (for JPA), but I don't think this is the best solution.

I think using a DTO instead of the entity itself would be better and more elegant than evicting the object from the session manually.